# How do you determine if the velocity in momentum is negative or not?

Tags: momentum, buoyancy

I am doing a momentum worksheet. Focusing on basic, p = mv and discussing positive and negative momentum. Where "Momentum can be negative if the velocity is negative." .?

"How does a balloon fly? (be specific and use physics terms)"

Since it is a balloon and it's in it 's nature to fly up, would my calculations run as so: p = m(v)?

or

Helium is lighter than air, so momentum is p = m(-v)?

Comment: Why is the question title about velocity and the body about balloons?

Comment: What do you mean? Obviously, you can describe a balloon going upwards as its velocity (and its momentum) being in the upward direction. That is just a restatement of what it means to say that the balloon is going upwards. But if you want to know the mechanism of how/why it does so then the explanation is precisely given by buoyant force. It simply doesn't make sense to say "explain to me how A happens without using the explanation of how A happens".

Comment: Regardless, as pointed out by another comment. please consider changing your title to suit the body of your question. Or, explain in the body how the title relates to the rest of the body of your question -- because it is extremely unclear.

Comment: FWIW: A balloon does not _fly_ if "flight" means motion through the air. If you ever go for a hot-air balloon ride, one thing you will notice is that you feel absolutely no wind while the balloon is aloft. That's because the balloon moves with the air. It _floats_, embedded in the air, rather than flying through the air like a bird or an airplane.

Comment: Thank you all, very great feedback! I'm just not understanding. I've made the suggested edits, please reconsider my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you can describe a balloon going upwards as its velocity (and its momentum) being in the upward direction. That is just a restatement of what it means to say that the balloon is going upwards. But if you want to know the mechanism of how/why it does so then the explanation is precisely given by buoyant force. It simply doesn't make sense to say "explain to me how A happens without using the explanation of how A happens".

Having said that, there are often situations in physics where you can provide explanations for a phenomenon in multiple different ways. However, since there is only one physics, if an explanation $A$ is true then another true explanation $B$ ought to be related to $A$ in one of the following ways:

- $B$ is a deeper explanation which engulfs explanation $A$. For example, the explanation of why an apple falls towards the earth can be given using both Newtonian gravity and general relativity -- here, general relativity is a deeper theory that includes Newtonian gravity in a limit.
- $A$ is a deeper explanation of $B$ but $B$ is still a good enough approximation of $A$ as far as the phenomenon at hand is concerned. This is just a reverse of the situation described in the earlier bullet point. Again, with the same example, you can see that one can explain the fall of an apple using general relativity but one can also explain it using Newtonian gravity because the latter is a good enough approximation of the former near the earth's surface for slow-moving apples.
- $B$ is just a restatement of $A$ using a different language. Here, the restatement can either be trivial and boring or it can also be path-breaking. By restatement, I just mean that the two explanations do not differ in their physical content/claims.

  - For example, you can explain how the interference pattern appears in a double-slit experiment using either wave-mechanics or using the path-integral formalism. Either one is a restatement of the other, but as you can see, the word "restatement" does not necessarily imply unimportance. An example of a highly non-trivial and very fruitful restatement would be dualities in QFT.
  - However, there are also trivial restatements. For example, I can say that the apple falls to the earth because of gravity. Or, I can say that the apple falls to the earth because the earth exerts a force on the apple towards its center and this force depends on the masses and the distance in a certain way. Here, I have just unpacked the word "gravity", but it is nothing new. To someone who already understands what gravity means, this is a trivial restatement.

Of course, this is a made-up categorization. We shouldn't (because we can't) impose our categorizations on physics because physics has a way of surprising us. However, this categorization is fair enough to give an approximate idea of how explanations usually work in familiar physics.

---

Now, a constructive way to frame the same question would be to ask as to whether the explanation via buoyance force can be rephrased in a different language that still describes the same physics? My point is that you can't simply demand that one ought to have such a second explanation. As always, you can say how Newtonian mechanics and buoyant forces ultimately arise from quantum mechanics and thus, quantum mechanics is another explanation. However, this is not very useful as anyone can see. This is an example of how the deeper framework does not always provide a useful explanation for a phenomenon occurring at an emergent level.

Finally, there is an explanation for the balloon going upwards that doesn't use the word "buoyant". The reason why a Helium balloon goes upwards when you release it in the force of gravity that acts on the balloon is smaller than the force on the balloon coming from the pressure due to the outer air on the boundary of the balloon. And the direction of this latter force is upwards so the balloon accelerates upwards. See, I didn't use the word "buoyant". But, of course, I am just restating what is meant by the phrase "buoyant force".